# url over extending in page

Tags: urls

I am writing a thesis paper, however one portion of the paper extends past the paragraph limit.

```
Word Match Generator addresses the need for computer science instructors be able to teach computer science students new vocabulary from anywhere in the world. Our tool helps students develop the necessary vocabulary for understanding computer science concepts through word matching exercises. The contribution from our research is a web-based tool for automatically generating a word matching exercises. Now instructors can enter the terms and their descriptions to generate a HTML page and share the URL with students. The tool is freely available from \href{\url{http://livelab.georgiasouthern.edu/wordmatchgenerator}}{http://livelab.georgiasouthern.edu/wordmatchgenerator}. It enables the instructors to guide the students in need, consequently leading to a better learning experience. The effectiveness of our application is supported by the research shown in \cite{Arifah}, \cite{Dewi}, \cite{Manik}, \cite{Masri}, \cite{Nikmah}.
```

The problem can be seen in the attached screenshot
[image]

Expected:
the paragraph should contain all the url

Actual:
the link sticks out of the paragraph

Comment: don't put \url inside the first \href argument. It is only \href{https: ...}.

Comment: Any update here?